# Convert JSON Dict to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have what appears to be a very simple JSON dict I need to convert into a Pandas dataframe. The dict is being pulled in for me as a string which I have little control over.

```
{
  "data": "[{'key1':'value1'}]"
}
```

I have tried the usual methods such as pd.read_json() and json_normalize() etc but can't seem to get it anywhere close. Has anyone a few different suggestions to try. I think ive see every error message python has at this stage.

Comment: That's not JSON, looks like a string representation of a list with dicts. You could try to parse it with ``ast.literal_eval``

Comment: While this is valid JSON, it only contains a single key `data` with a long string value. Anything inside double quotes is just a string. If you want that content to be parsed as a list of dictionaries, you'll have to fix the code that produces this string and remove the extra quotes. Otherwise you'll have to deserialize the document, retrieve the `data` string and deserialize that again

Comment: @MikeScotty that was actually one of my earlier attempts. I tried to use ast.literal_eval as I had used it elsewhere. But I recieve an error  "raise ValueError(f'malformed node or string: {node!r}')
ValueError: malformed node or string: <ast.Name object at 0x122dc80a0>"

Comment: Well, the string value of data contains one ``}`` too many to be valid. Also, converting ``{'key1':'value1','key1':'value1'}`` to a dict will turn into ``{'key1': 'value1'}`` - because the same key can only appear once in a dict.

Comment: @MikeScotty sorry, those were typos on my part. Have simplified now what it really looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your JSON data is improperly formatted. The double quotations around the brackets indicate that everything within those double quotes is a string. Essentially the data is considered a string and not an array of values. Remove the double quotes and to create an array in your JSON file.

```
{
  "data": [{"key1":"value1"}]
}
```

This will create the array and allow your JSON to be properly parsed using your previous stated methods.

Comment: I think everyone was somewhat correct. It was the double quotes causing the issue. Once these were removed before conversion. All worked as expected. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

The example provided is a single key, but in general you can use pandas to load json and nested json with `pd.json_normalize(yourjsonhere)`

Comment: This was the first thing I tried. No luck. With error   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py", line 423, in _json_normalize
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError

Comment: I did an exact copy of your json and used the method and it works for me.